# How to enable JVM logs in Logs and Trace in Websphere console

Tags: websphere, logging, zos

Whenever I go into the tab TroubleShooting->Logs and Trace->Server I get the general properties section in which there's only a link of Change Log Details Level. I've changed the tracing inside to reflect for my apps. But beyond this option I'm not able to see the log files inside WAS. We have WAS on Z/OS and I'm able to view logs on the mainframe. Is there any file or script that we need to run to enable JVM logs?

Answer (score 0):

- On AIX, linux and Windows, when I go TroubleShooting -> Logs and Trace -> Server , I get several links in general properties section, one of which is 'Diagnostic Trace' through which I can enable/disable tracing and configure where the log files shall be located at, their sizes, rollover settings etc.

  The fact that you don't see this link either suggests this is something z/OS specific, or you don't have privileges to perform runtime operations. You may check if you're logging in with a user that is in Administrators group (you may check you user at Users and Groups -> Administrative User Roles).
- There are two tabs at the screen that you change trace options, namely 'configuration' and 'runtime'. If you are making changes at configuration tab, you have to recycle the server for trace string to become active. You may try using Runtime tab if you haven't done so.
- You may try enabling trace using wsadmin as in  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftxml_profiletrace.html

  - turn on trace (putting your own trace string)

    ```
    ts = AdminControl.queryNames('type=TraceService,node=mynode,process=server1,*')
    AdminControl.setAttribute(ts, 'traceSpecification', 'com.ibm.=all=enabled')
    ```
  - turn off trace

    ```
    ts = AdminControl.queryNames('type=TraceService,node=mynode,process=server1,*')
    AdminControl.setAttribute(ts, 'traceSpecification', 'com.ibm.*=all=disabled')
    ```